# How to use ImageDataGenerator when your train/test/validation data are not sorted into folders

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I'm using the Stanford Dog dataset http://vision.stanford.edu/aditya86/ImageNetDogs/ in which all the images are stored in a single folder.  References to those images that belong in the training and test set are stored in a list; e.g.

```
# Load pre-constructed train/test arrays from Stanford Dataset
train_list = loadmat('./lists/train_list.mat')
test_list = loadmat('./lists/test_list.mat')
```

Eventually I  read in these images and store their values in arrays (X_train and y_train).  I now want to do data augmentation similar to this tutorial:

https://www.learnopencv.com/keras-tutorial-fine-tuning-using-pre-trained-models/

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
      rescale=1./255,
      rotation_range=20,
      width_shift_range=0.2,
      height_shift_range=0.2,
      horizontal_flip=True,
      fill_mode='nearest')

validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

# Change the batchsize according to your system RAM
train_batchsize = 100
val_batchsize = 10


train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        train_dir,
        target_size=(image_size, image_size),
        batch_size=train_batchsize,
        class_mode='categorical')

validation_generator = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        validation_dir,
        target_size=(image_size, image_size),
        batch_size=val_batchsize,
        class_mode='categorical',
        shuffle=False)
```

However, because my data are stored in arrays (e.g. X_train and X_val) I can't figure out a way to do data augmentation without separating them into folders.  Any ideas?

Comment: "Eventually I read in these images and store their values in arrays (X_train and y_train)" if you have already read the images and stored them in an array then why are you using `flow_from_directory`? Use `flow` instead.

Comment: I didn't know of the existence of flow.  That's the answer to my question.  Thanks!